# exit previous recursions when we find the answer

Tags: c, recursion, exit

I have a question in c programming(may in other languages too)
consider this program:

(I want to write the last input number that is dividable by 3 without using arrays and ... just with recursion)

```
int func( int n )
{

    int a;
    if (n==0)
        return 0;
                scanf("%d",&a);
        function(n-1);
    if(a%3==0)
    {
        printf("%d\n",a);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

but unfortunately, it prints numbers dividable by 3 in reverse order(I want just the last number dividable by 3)

Comment: Friend. You should use divisible instead of dividable. Especially in the context of numbers. While dividable has an arguably more straight forward derivation, it is not a part of well spoken, or written, English.

Comment: I suppose you meant `func(n-1)` instead of `function(n-1)`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY true, but isn't `(a%3)==0` easier here? ;)

Comment: @Ctx Perhaps, I was misleading the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the value to print, if it is valid and no other valid value has been returned previously (using -1 as invalid marker, for example)

```
int func (int n) {
    int a;

    if (n == 0)
       return -1;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    int ret = func(n-1);
    if ((ret == -1) && (a%3 == 0))
        ret = a;
    return ret;
}
```

Now you can print the return value of `func()`.

```
printf("%d\n", func(100)); // For 100 values
```

Comment: `int ret = func(n-1)` I suppose. OP seems to have made a mistake.

Comment: @J...S correct, thanks... and fixed an error of my own ;)